# Calculate number of pixels and more variables by classes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, band

I have one band raster that has 3 possible values: 1,2 or 3.
I want to calculate for this raster different variables, for example how many pixels we have for each values and also to do some band math for them.
Another challenge is that the raster I have is one but it contains data about different polygons.

My end goal is to have kind of tabular data based on the different polygons that will contain data about how many pixels I have in each polygon, how many pixels are in each class, etc.

Comment: Please stick to one specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy and scipy for that: the following script shows the basic principle how to access rasterdata with numpy via gdal:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from osgeo import gdal

'Active Layer must be a raster layer
raster = iface.activeLayer()
rl = raster.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
ds = gdal.Open(rl) #open raster with gdal
data = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()) #make a numpy array
print(stats.describe(data)) 'some stats
```

Now you have the whole scipy/numpy universe to play around with the rasterdata. More information on scipy/numpy statistics you will find here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html